# Redirect User to Case Detail from a different New Case screen

Tags: case, casefeed

This might not be possible. But we want to use a New Case layout that has just a few fields on it (Account, Contact, Case Status, Subject and Description), then redirect to a Case Detail layout that has many other fields on it (Description, Resolution, Case Type, Product and all the dependent fields etc). So I need 2 different case layouts. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You could create VisualForce wizard to acomplish that extending Case standard controller only to perform the navigation between the 2 pages.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_quick_start_wizard.htm

To assing the VForce page, you have to edit [New] Content Source in Action Buttons, Links, and Actions of Case Object. You must change Standard Salesforce Page with the created VF page